# Elasticsearch sort not working on nested array in ascending ascending

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Elasticsearch sort not working on nested field. It's showing mixed of ascending and descending values. Like 40, 30, 50 . It's not showing in ascending order like this: 30, 40, 50

Query:

```
"sort": [
{
  "x.price": {
    "order": "asc",
    "nested_path": "x"
  }
}
```

]